# Flutter web app domain extension using getx routing

Tags: flutter

The requirement is as follows.
We need to extend our flutter web app hosted domain with some other domain which is mostly based api. If the flutter web app hosted domain is using that base api we should work whole api with that base api only. For example let's say flutter web app is hosted in some domain like flutter-app.web.app and the APIs are working on basic of BASE_API_A. Now if we use the URL as flutter-app.web.app?URL=BASE_API_B then whole app(all the api calls) should work on the basic of BASE_API_B. We are using getx for routing and state management. It has some authentication also which we manage using middleware. I am not able to solve the requirement. Can anyone please let me know how to solve this issue.